# Microsoft Office Picture Manager not showing thumbails

Tags: microsoft-office, android, preview, pictures

Normally  Microsoft Office Picture Manager has the option to show thumbnails of all the images in the current folder, but when I have my phone connected and viewing images on the SD card it doesn't. Why does this happen and can I change this?

Comment: Is the SD card write-protected?

Comment: How do I tell?.